# Explicit casting doesn't work in default model binding

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, casting, type-conversion

I am using ASP.NET MVC2 and Entity Framework. I am going to simplify the situation a little; hopefully it will make it clearer, not more confusing!

I have a controller action to create address, and the country is a lookup table (in other words, there is a one-to-many relationship between Country and Address classes). Let's say for clarity that the field in the Address class is called Address.Land. And, for the purposes of the dropdown list, I am getting Country.CountryID and Country.Name.

I am aware of [Model vs. Input validation](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/01/input-validation-vs-model-validation-in-aspnet-mvc.html). So, if I call the dropdown field *formLand* - I can make it work. But if I call the field **Land** (that is, matching the variable in Address class) - I am getting the following error:

> "The parameter conversion from type
>   'System.String' to type 'App.Country'
>   failed because no type converter can
>   convert between these types."

OK, this makes sense. A string (CountryID) comes from the form and the binder doesn't know how to convert it to Country type. So, I wrote the converter:

```
namespace App {
    public partial class Country {
        public static explicit operator Country(string countryID) {
            AppEntities context = new AppEntities();
            Country country = (Country) context.GetObjectByKey(
                new EntityKey("AppEntities.Countries", "CountryID", countryID));
            return country;
        }
    }
}
```

FWIW, I tried both explicit and implicit. I tested it from the controller - `Country c = (Country)"fr"` - and it works fine. However, it never got invoked when the View is posted. I am getting the same "no type converter" error in the model.

Any ideas how to hint to the model binder that there **is** a type converter?
Thanks

Comment: My $0.02: Bind to view/edit models, not entities.

Comment: I don't disagree - but the problem with the dropdown that I am describing here would be exactly the same

Comment: Not really. Your view model property would be a `string`, not an entity. Binding would work. You can then update the entity with a query on the string.

Comment: and this *query on the string* is what I am trying to avoid in the first place!

Comment: You can convert the submitted value to an entity-which-already-exists-in-the-database in any way you care to, but you're still converting it, no matter what you choose to call it. Don't like the word "query"? Pick one you like. But choosing a different word doesn't change the essence of what you're doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A type converter is not the same as an explicit or implicit conversion, it's an object that converts values between various types.

I think you need to create a class inherited from `TypeConverter` that converts between `Country` and other types, and apply the `TypeConverterAttribute` to your class to specify the converter to use :

```
using System.ComponentModel;

public class CountryConverter : TypeConverter
{
    // override CanConvertTo, CanConvertFrom, ConvertTo and ConvertFrom
    // (not sure about other methods...)
}

[TypeConverter(typeof(CountryConverter))]
public partial class Country
{

...

}
```

Comment: Wow! That is a huge step in the right direction... I didn't know about TypeConverter. Thank you very much. I also looked at Microsoft's HowTo: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ayybcxe5.aspx

Now an interesting thing happens. Apparently, EF generated CountryConverter, but it is derived from EntityObject and apparently doesn't have anything to do with TypeConverter (weird, if true). So, I created class LandConverter, decorated Country with [TypeConverter(typeof(LandConverter))].

(continued...)

Comment: I am still not getting to the breakpoint in LandConverter:CanConvertFrom or LandConverter:ConvertFrom. However, the exception sounds a little different:
"The parameter conversion from type 'System.String' to type 'App.CountryConverter' failed because no type converter can convert between these types."

Note CountryConverter which is the generated class. Not my LandConverter. So, now I am even more confused.
(hm - only 1 comment allowed per 15 sec ;)