# Explicit cast string to class fails in Equals

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

As part of a website I'm working on, users may need to update partial information for each ticket submitted. When I test out a `TryUpdateModel` with this particular class which has an explicit operator to convert it to a string, I get an `InvalidCastException`. I've managed to isolate this exception down from all the previous MVC code to this:

**Class**

```
public class ConversionOperator
{
    public ConversionOperator()
    {
        FullName = string.Empty;
    }

    public ConversionOperator(string fullName)
    {
        FullName = fullName;
    }

    public string FullName { get; set; }

    public static explicit operator string(ConversionOperator item)
    {
        return item == null
            ? string.Empty
            : item.FullName;
    }

    public static explicit operator ConversionOperator(string item)
    {
        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(item)
            ? new ConversionOperator()
            : new ConversionOperator(item);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        ConversionOperator other = (ConversionOperator) obj;

        return FullName == other.FullName;
    }
}
```

**Unit Test**

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Verify_Conversion_To_String()
    {
        ConversionOperator first;

        first = new ConversionOperator("Henry Beauford Autumnbottom Elderberry McClatchen");

        Assert.AreEqual(first.FullName, (string) first); // passes
        Assert.IsTrue(first.Equals("Henry Beauford Autumnbottom Elderberry McClatchen")); // throws exception
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Verify_Conversion_From_String()
    {
        string name = "Henry Beauford Autumnbottom Elderberry McClatchen";

        Assert.AreEqual((ConversionOperator) name, new ConversionOperator(name));
    }
```

The first Assert in `Verify_Conversion_To_String` passes, but the second one fails, throwing an `InvalidCastException`. It's clear that the .NET Framework knows `obj` is a `string`, but the explicit conversion isn't being called.

Changing from a cast to `as ConversionOperator` produces a null object, which isn't correct either.

Comment: Have you run this through the debugger to see what type `obj` actually is?

Comment: I've tried many times. Since this exception's being produced by `TryUpdateModel`, I can't get the debugger to actually hit the line in question. The exception message explicitly says, "Unable to cast object of type `System.String to type `Framework.Names.ProperName`." I'm open to any suggestions, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by implementing `IEquatable<string>`:

```
public bool Equals(string other)
{
    ConversionOperator item = new ConversionOperator(other);

    return this.Equals(item);
}
```

Now the unit tests pass, and I'm going to go bang my head on the wall until I forget that I asked this question.

Comment: Yep, that's the other way to do it. :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are passing in a `String` to your Equals method. If that's the case then it will fail the cast to `ProperName`.

What you will can do is create a different Equals method that takes a string (or several strings) and tests those against the `ProperName` **properties** to see if they'd match:

```
public bool Equals(string fullName, t1 middleNameOptions, t2 displayOptions)
{
    return this.FullName == item.FullName
        && this.MiddleNameOptions == item.MiddleNameOptions
        && this.DisplayOptions == item.DisplayOptions;
}
```

Comment: Yep -- you've got me there. Why is this happening, though? I would've expected the explicit cast I defined to override the default conversion operator.

Comment: @jwiscarson - the `explicit operator` applies to *conversions* **not** *comparisons* http://simpleprogrammer.com/2013/01/20/implicit-and-explicit-conversion-operators-in-c/

Comment: The exception gets thrown on the line `ProperName other = (ProperName)obj;` I'm not comparing the objects at this point.

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404801/explicit-casting-doesnt-work-in-default-model-binding).

Comment: @ChristopherStevenson, I've updated the source code with a reproducible sample that doesn't use model binding. Whatever is going on here is happening in a very specific set of circumstances.

Comment: In C# explicit conversions are not automatic, so you can't compare a string and your `ConversionOperator` class without (a) _explicitly_ converting the string or (b) making the conversion implicit. (Or you could set up the Equals method to handle it). In order for your cast n the Equals function to work, you would need to define an object to ConverisonOperator cast (or take ToString() of the object).

Comment: I'm not following you here. Can you update your answer to show how I'm not presently explicitly converting the string? Making the conversion implicit doesn't fix this problem, and there isn't a way to define an explicit operator to convert from an object (which is how I'm interpreting your last suggestion, although I may be wrong here).

Comment: Done. (I called obj.ToString() method, which for strings simply returns the string.)

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the exception from occurring, you can call the object's `ToString()` method:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    if (obj == null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    ProperName item =  (ConversionOperator) obj.ToString();


    return FullName == item.FullName
        && MiddleNameOptions == item.MiddleNameOptions
        && DisplayOptions == item.DisplayOptions;
}
```

#### Notes:

In order for the TryUpdateModel method to bind a model to the given prefix (of form data), you will likely need an implicit cast.

If you look at [the source for the Controller class](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/Controller.cs), can see that under the hood, the `DefaultModelBinder` is used.

The `DefaultModelBinder` has limitations, and is generally better with a specialized model, which is then mapped to your domain model (perhaps with manually written code, or with [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper))

If you can't change your approach, then I suggest creating a [Custom Model Binder](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/605595/ASP-NET-MVC-Custom-Model-Binder) which will give you direct control of how the form is translated to the model.

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't a `DefaultModelBinder` problem. I wrote a Unit Test in the source library (which is in a different solution altogether) and reproduced the problem there. I've also tried implicit casts -- the line in question that's producing an error is definitely the explicit cast.